# Swift: static init()

Tags: swift, initialization, overloading, swift5

I recently came across code which looked like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static init(_ bar : Int) -> Int { ... }
}
```

Am I right to assume that this is merely an arbitrary function which can however be called as `Foo(42)`?
The result of such a call would still be an `Int` and doesn't result in the construction of a `Foo` object whatsoever.

Comment: If so, such trickery will no longer be needed starting in Swift 5.2, which provides a legitimate `callAsFunction`. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0253-callable.md

Comment: That's simply invalid: "error: declaration cannot be marked 'static'"

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You're right. I can't find the line in the original code base anymore, seems to have been introduced during refactoring.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Maybe at the time that code was written that loophole had not been closed by the syntax checker. Or maybe it was a suggestion.  `Foo(bar:42)` is indeed desugared to `Foo.init(bar:42)`, so one can imagine this kind of overloading might trick the compiler. Anyway, as I say, in Swift 5.2 there’s a real way to do it.

Comment: By the way, I filed a bug back in Swift 1 insisting that `init` declarations should _all_ be marked `static`, because they are indeed type methods, not instance methods. But it didn’t gain any traction. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` in *Swift* is reserved for creating the *initializer* of a particular type.

You can instead try creating a **`subscript`** with `static` modifier if that solves your purpose.

```
public class Foo {
    static subscript(_ bar: Int) -> Int {
        return bar + 10
    }
}
```

You can use it like,

```
let value = Foo[1] //11
```

The above code won't create any `Foo` type instance.